# Why tf.keras.Model training flag significantly alters the prediction result?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I was recently going through the [tensorflow pix2pix tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix) and after playing with it a bit I unexpectedly realized that there is a major difference between the predictions of a [tf.keras.Model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) (In this case the Generator() from the tutorial) where one of the prediction use the [training flag](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#call) to **true** and the other to **false**.

Here is the code to demonstrate the issue:

```
# ...Tutorial steps where I load the model instead of creating a new one...
checkpoint.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))


for example_input, example_target in test_dataset.take(1):
  train_res1 = generate_images(generator, example_input, example_target)       # Function definition as per tutorial expect that I return the 'Predicted Image'
  train_res2 = generate_images(generator, example_input, example_target)       # Now considering training is true (will alter the model), a small RGB difference is expected
  notrain_res2 = generate_images2(generator, example_input, example_target)    # Identical to 'generate_images' except that 'training=false', should be identical or similar to last one.
  
  r_avg = np.average(train_res1[:,:, 0])
  g_avg = np.average(train_res1[:,:, 1])
  b_avg = np.average(train_res1[:,:, 2])
  print(f"Training flag true iteration#1 = R average: {r_avg}, G average: {g_avg}, B average: {b_avg}")
  r_avg = np.average(train_res2[:,:, 0])
  g_avg = np.average(train_res2[:,:, 1])
  b_avg = np.average(train_res2[:,:, 2])
  print(f"Training flag true iteration#2 = R average: {r_avg}, G average: {g_avg}, B average: {b_avg}")
  r_avg = np.average(notrain_res2[:,:, 0])
  g_avg = np.average(notrain_res2[:,:, 1])
  b_avg = np.average(notrain_res2[:,:, 2])
  print(f"Training flag false            = R average: {r_avg}, G average: {g_avg}, B average: {b_avg}")
```

Just to avoid any confusion, here is the code of **generate_images2** which is identical to **generate_images** from tutorial except that 'training=False' and I return the prediction:

```
def generate_images2(model, test_input, tar):
  prediction = model(test_input, training=False)
  plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))

  display_list = [test_input[0], tar[0], prediction[0]]
  title = ['Input Image', 'Ground Truth', 'Predicted Image']

  for i in range(3):
    plt.subplot(1, 3, i+1)
    plt.title(title[i], color = "w")
    # Getting the pixel values in the [0, 1] range to plot.
    plt.imshow(display_list[i] * 0.5 + 0.5)
    plt.axis('off')
  plt.show()
  return display_list[2]
```

[Here](https://ibb.co/d4c67nH) you can vizualize my concerns with the [training flag](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#call).

- As expected there are minor differences between the RGB values of iteration#1 and iteration#2 with training flag = True. This is expected due to training model alterations.
- However when training flag = False, I would expect the RGB values to be similar or identical to the iteration#2 with training flag = True but if you look at the door in the yellow and red circle  s the RGB values are clearly different.
- The result is pretty much always better with training=True

**Question:** Why tf.keras.Model training flag significantly alters the prediction result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer from the Tensorflow repo:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36936

There are some things that only happen during training, for example dropout is used. If `training=False` then dropout layers are ignored (see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dropout)

Comment: Thx @mstreffo. This is a bit unfortunate since even though the result is quite ok with 'training=False'  the result is pretty much always better with 'training=True'.

Comment: That's interesting. As this is from a TF tutorial, have you logged this as an issue on with the TF dev team?